# Determine if a String is a SOAPMessage

Tags: java, xml, validation, soap

I need to check if a String object is a SOAPMessage.  In other words, if I can convert a String to a SOAPMessage cleanly without any errors.

I have a list of String messages in a file that may or may not be SOAPMessages, and also if they are, they are formatted differently:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>...</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<soapenv:Envelope>...</soapenv:Envelope>
```

They may also be other types, so I cannot use xml validation technique to validate the SOAPMessage and determine it is so.

Currently, I am converting it to a SOAPMessage object, and detecting any errors in the process to determine if it is a valid SOAPMessage.

```
try {
    // TODO Validate SOAPMessage
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.getBytes());
    MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage payload = mf.createMessage(null, in);
} catch (SOAPException e) {
    throw new SOAPException("Error in Creating SOAP Message Parts."
            + " The Request Message may be Invalid.", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IOException("Input Read Error. No Input Received.", e);
}
```

However, I am looking for a way to make the process easier and not have to go through this process if the message is not a SOAPMessage.  This process also throws a System.out.err message, which I do not want to see.

I have looked online, but when I search for this topic, I only find xml validation of the SOAPMessage, or similar techniques.

Comment: How about you validate the String for XML, then with tag name like SOAP-ENV:Envelope?

Comment: Does each message in the file appear on one line?  I am assuming they do. You could read each line from the file and just check the the line (in lowercase) starts with "<soap" and contains "envelope"? Obviously not the most elegant solution but would save relying on the exceptions although when you decide a message is a SOAP message that could still be invalid and throw an exception.

Comment: @Keerthivasan I should have been more specific.  I am working with REST/SOAP in networking.  I have to determine if a message is SOAP or REST from a network packet data.  Since the data for REST could also be XML, that would not work.  Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: @slarge Thanks for the reply, that is very helpful.  I will try it, but it would still be more helpful if there was an absolute solution rather than a rough one like checking strings for keywords.